# Is it possible to modify ECMAScript module source code (and change its behaviour) during run-time?

Tags: javascript

My question was spurred by [the notorious attack](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116) on the Copay cryptocurrency wallet in 2018. To recap it briefly, there was a library, `event-stream`, the wallet depended on. Using social engineering, hackers gained ability to change this library and publish its new versions through `npm`. Injected malicious code was intended to carry out the following things:

1. [Payload A](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloada-js) (a chunk of code) deciphers [Payload B](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloadb-js) and runs it with the aid of Node.js [`Module.prototype._compile`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e2a6399be742f53103474d9fc1e56fadf7f90ccc/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1055) function. Payload B exports a function (with `module.exports`), which then gets executed. *(These code steps are given in much more convenient way in the first comment of the github issue)*.
2. This function objective was to inject yet another deciphered [Payload C](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloadc-js). Its code was introduced by means of `writeFileSync()` into `ReedSolomonDecoder.js` file, which in fact was a part of a lib dependency (of a module inside the `./node_modules` folder).
3. When someone calls `require('./ReedSolomonDecoder.js')`, injected Payload 3, in turn, would call `require('bitcore-wallet-client/lib/credentials.js')` and fiddle with its function prototypes, so for now on user passwords would send to a hackers server.

It is worth taking note of the fact it is possible here for a running application to modify modules files the application dependent on during run-time, affecting their behaviour, as the CommonJS module system makes use of `readFileSync()` under the hood or something like this to load a required module (please, correct me here if I am essentially wrong).

And what about ECMAScript modules (let's restrict ourself here to static `import`s)? To the best of my knowledge, modifying of `ReedSolomonDecoder.js` file on run-time can't lead to any change to this module behaviour. The spec prescribes run through a loop of the module dependencies (step 10 of [`InnerModuleEvaluation()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-innermoduleevaluation)) and alternately execute their [`ExecuteModule()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module) routine, which supposes the parsed source text is already set for the module (the [`ECMAScriptCode`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#table-additional-fields-of-source-text-module-records) internal field).

Is my understanding correct and it is impossible in the ECMAScript modules world to bring about any effect on behaviour of a module in the dependency graph during run-time by changing its source code?

Comment: Changing JavaScript source code won't do any good once the code has been parsed. However, it's possible to change `.prototype` objects etc.

Comment: I don't know ECMAScript `import` internals well, but I do know `require`. I have [an answer on SoftwareEngineering.SE about `require`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201212/51295), explaining how the first call to `require("foo")` runs `foo` and every subsequent call does not. Instead it pulls the previously-generated object from `require.cache["foo"]`, so if you modify `require.cache["foo"].someProp` you modify it everywhere (which is the same as modifying `require("foo").someProp`). This doesn't require modifying source code; modules outputs are effectively mutable globals.

Comment: Also it's not super-clear what you're really asking here.

Comment: Yes, as long as the engine does not provide any way to dynamically load code (e.g. with `import(...)` or `eval(...)` )

Comment: @Pointy My question is boiled down in the last paragraph.

Comment: @apsillers I don't know why didn't the hackers just swap properties of the exports module object on the spot and opted for this involved way, but if they did so, there was a reason (probably, the target module shouldn't be executed right after the first injected code gets executed).